# SAN wildcard for whole domain TLD

Tags: macos, ssl, san

Is it possible to make SAN wildcard self-signed certificate for whole local TLD (.test)?

```
[ san ]
subjectAltName                  = @alt_names

[ alt_names ]
DNS.1                           = localhost
DNS.2                           = *.test
```

Then i've added this certificate to a Keychain (MacOS), but browser complains, when i try to visit: domain.test, it says that certificate belongs to a localhost, but not to a domain.test

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is technically valid according to [RFC 6125](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125#section-6.4.3).

However, many web browsers have decided to reject wildcards on the TLD for security reasons.

See: [Can a wildcard SSL certificate be issued for a second level domain? | Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6873/can-a-wildcard-ssl-certificate-be-issued-for-a-second-level-domain)

Comment: So there's no workaround? Can i force Chrome to accept it?